# Loop over list within a list

Tags: ansible

I am trying to loop over following object:

```
{
    "ctfd_api_key": "API-KEY",
    "url": "http://172.19.0.1:8000",
    "hosts": [
        {
            "host": "dev-01",
            "team": {
                "name": "fairelronds",
                "password": "f0475264f5b88474376b149968e26b8d",
                "members": [
                    {
                        "name": "unbalancedrat",
                        "password": "d6b544ab0588757e8b296534659e6fd0"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "popularocelot",
                        "password": "7a2f72cb44381ff416e7e38696239ddf"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "challenges": [
                {
                    ...
                },
                {
                    ...
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "host": "dev-02",
            "team": {
                "name": "robustents",
                "password": "48eeeced36167a78a92ceb10b6f527a4",
                "members": [
                    {
                        "name": "barbaricsalamander",
                        "password": "406ed7c9467fb2c0ce6c9cf416d680a3"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "quietshrimp",
                        "password": "4652531efb5a8837d14227ef27ba67a2"
                    }
                ]
            },
             "challenges": [
                {
                    ...
                },
                {
                    ...
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            ...
        }
     ]
}
```

What I am only interested in the role is the member list. I can not create a flat list though as in a later step I need the group name of each team member. The executing role would look like this:

```
- name: 'create users'
  nislab.ctfd.ctfd_user:
    url: '{{ url }}'
    ctfd_api_key: '{{ ctfd_api_key }}'
    name: '{{ item.name }}'
    password: '{{ item.password }}'
    state: '{{ state }}'
  loop: "{{  hosts | subelements('team.members') }}"
```

So the steps should be to loop over N hosts and then loop over the N team members. What would the ideal looping method be here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the JSON data in variable *obj1*, use *json_query*, e.g.

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ obj1.hosts|json_query('[].team.{name: name, members: members}') }}"
```

should give the list

```yaml
  msg:
  - members:
    - name: unbalancedrat
      password: d6b544ab0588757e8b296534659e6fd0
    - name: popularocelot
      password: 7a2f72cb44381ff416e7e38696239ddf
    name: fairelronds
```

You can iterate the list *with_subelements* .e.g.

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: |-
          team: {{ item.0.name }}
          name: {{ item.1.name }}
          pswd: {{ item.1.password }}
      with_subelements:
        - "{{ obj1.hosts|json_query('[].team.{name: name, members: members}') }}"
        - members
```

should give

```yaml
  msg: |-
    team: fairelronds
    name: unbalancedrat
    pswd: d6b544ab0588757e8b296534659e6fd0

  msg: |-
    team: fairelronds
    name: popularocelot
    pswd: 7a2f72cb44381ff416e7e38696239ddf
```